# Accessing the Corda Shell using the node's ssh pem file

Tags: shell, corda

Is there a way of configuring the shell to log in with only the private key pem file (rather than password) please? I tried `chmod 400 ssh/hostkey.pem` and passing that in `ssh -p 2223 testuser@localhost -i ./ssh/hostkey.pem` but the shell forces password auth.

thanks
Fuzz

Comment: Hello @dazraf, have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think at the moment, Corda do not support the concept of logging in via key.pem